# Proguard - Can't find common super class of [android/database/Cursor]

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'm facing an issue with proguard where I'm getting the following after building:

```
 (with 2 known super classes) and [com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzgg] (with 1 known super classes)
```

This happens after adding the following dependency :

```
implementation 'com.appnexus.opensdk.mediatedviews:appnexus-googleplay-mediation:6.1.1-18.2.0'
```

This is my proguard config for Google play services :

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,Signature

#-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
#-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

-dontobfuscate

-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt

# ======= Google Play Services =======
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final *** CREATOR;
}

-keep @interface android.support.annotation.Keep
-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class *
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keep @interface com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
  @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keep @interface com.google.android.gms.common.util.DynamiteApi
-keep public @com.google.android.gms.common.util.DynamiteApi class * {
  public <fields>;
  public <methods>;
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }

-dontwarn android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy

-dontwarn com.schibsted.domain.messaging.notifications.gcm.*
```

My question, is there some option I can add to proguard or some class I have to exclude to rectify this error.
Note: I've tried **-dontoptimize** but I end up with mostly warnings that don't allow me to run the app. And with **-dontpreverify** I end up getting

```
Duplicate jar entry [com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementJobService.class]
```